# Problem starting up Katalon spy (error message attached)

Tags: android, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I'm trying to start up the Katalon spy on Android and it gives me this error message, I was wondering if any of you guys knew what to do, I've followed a couple of installation guides and none of them mention it.

[image: The error message]

Answer (score 1):

> **1- What is the exact IP/Port you defined for the appium** before starting it?

It should be  0.0.0.0:4723. Because 127.0.0.1:4723 doesn't work in some systems.

> **2- Does the Adb server running?** It means does the CMD/Powershell return you device adb ID by typing "Adb devices" in cmd? If not please do the following:

Add a variable in **system environment** as mention below.

**ANDROID_HOME** : C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (Or any PATH that your android SDK located)

**JAVA_HOME**: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172

**ANDROID_SWT** : C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64

**ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS** : C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

Add below mention Path in **Path Variable** in the system environment. (If your SDK located in C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ )

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\bin;

C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin;

C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools;

C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;

C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;

C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk;

C:\Users[Your login name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\lib\x86_64\swt.jar;

By completing these steps your "Adb devices" command should works.

> **3- Are you define the Desired Capabilities** here: “Project” menu / “Settings” / “Desired Capabilities” / “Mobile” / “Android” ? If not please insert like this:

[image]

> **4- What does the version of the Appium?** It should be 1.12.x, Upper version like 1.13 or 1.14 isn't compatible with the Katalon Studio
>
> **5- Does another Automator or Hierarchy viewer running**? For example UiAutomator2 or TestNG (From IntelliJ or Eclipse), etc. If yes please terminate them excepts Katalon spy.

*I hope this helps*

*Regards*